# Reading values of one dictionary into another in python

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, machine-learning

So basically, i have a dictionary d, that reads from a text file "topics.txt"
"topics.txt", has lines in the following pattern:

1~britain~italy~india

2~spain~turkey

3~france

4~egypt~china~japan~iceland

and so on..

here, the numbers correspond to the files"1.txt","2.txt" and so on..that belong to the document "individual-articles'

In the dictionary "d" ,i classify all the files of the document "individual-articles" into classes that are the words given in topics.txt

so,the dictionary "d" with key values say, "britain","france" and "spain"  is of the form:

(Britain,[1,76,289]) where the files 1.txt,76.txt,289.txt come under the class "Britain"

(Spain,[2,8]) where the files 2.txt,8.txt come under the class "Spain"

(france,[3,99,12,43]) where the files 3.txt,99.txt,12.txt,43.txt come under "France" 
and so on..

Now i am creating another dictionary "word_count_dict" that contains the class name and the number of times the "class" appears in IT'S files, which can be obtained from "d".

ex:
word_count_dict must have:

(Britain,236)  where 236 is the number of times the word "Britain" appears in the files 1.txt,76.txt,289.txt

(France,56) where 56 is the number of occurrences of the word "france" in the files   3.txt,99.txt,12.txt,43.txt

and so on...

```
import collections
import sys
import os
import re
sys.stdout=open('dictionary.txt','w')
from collections import Counter
from glob import glob


folderpath='d:/individual-articles'
counter=Counter()

with open('topics.txt') as f:
    d= collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in f:
        value, *keys = line.strip().split('~')
        for key in filter(None, keys):
            d[key].append(value+".txt")

filepaths = glob(os.path.join(folderpath,'*.txt'))

def words_generator(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word
word_count_dict = {}
for file in filepaths:
    f = open(file,"r")
    words = words_generator(f)
    for word in words:
        if word not in word_count_dict:
              word_count_dict[word] = {"total":0}
        if file not in word_count_dict[word]:
              word_count_dict[word][file] = 0
        word_count_dict[word][file] += 1              
        word_count_dict[word]["total"] += 1        
for k in word_count_dict.keys():
    for filename in word_count_dict[k]:
        if filename == 'total': continue
        counter.update(filename)

for word, counts in word_count_dict.items():
    print(word, counts['total'])
```

So far i have tried this code, but i do not think that the files in d for that particular key are being checked for!

```
output:
d2=(["Britain",45],["France",56],["Spain",89],.....)
```

Where 45 is the number of times the word "Britain" occurs in the files: 1.txt,76.txt,289.txt

56 is the number of occurrences of the word "France" in the files:
3.txt,99.txt,12.txt,43.txt

the frequency of the occurrence of the word  "britain" is not checked for in the files 1.txt,76.txt,289.txt, that can be obtained from the dictionary "d", instead my program checks for all the files!

Comment: Please clarify your premise with sample data from the text files.

Comment: What is your input? What output you are getting? What is your expected output?

Comment: i get an error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\access_dict2.py", line 41, in <module>
    word_count_dict[word][file]= 0
KeyError: 'britain'

Comment: i want the word_count_dict to be printed!

Comment: Could you please use proper formatting in your question in order to made the thing more comprehensible? Or am I just to tired to accept the necessary effort to read you...

Comment: how do i read the values of d into word_count_dict?

Answer (score 0):

```
def word_count_dict(fname):
    from os.path import isfile
    if isfile(fname):
        d={}
        with open(fname) as fi:
            for line in fi:
                entries=line.split('~')
                for elem in entries[1:]:
                    d[elem]=d.get(elem,[])+[entries[0]]
        for k in d:
            print (k,len(d[k]))

word_count_dict('topics.txt')
```

I think this should work.